# I need some explanation about sorting nodes

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, compare, comparison

I am confused how this comparing works, for example the second if statement, if comparison > 0 it should be before currentItem, but the lines inside the if statement have confused me too much, can you explain it to me how they work?

By the way

```java
this.root
```

is an instance of ListItem
and the code doesn't use LinkedList or ArrayList class, the code below trying to emulate something in LinkedList i think, If my questions need more explanation, tell me please.
Best regards

```java
@Override
    public boolean addItem(ListItem newItem) {
        if(this.root == null){
            this.root = newItem;
            return true;
        }
        ListItem currentItem = this.root;
        while (currentItem != null){
            int comparison = currentItem.compareTo(newItem);
            if (comparison < 0){
                if (currentItem.next()!=null){
                    currentItem = currentItem.next();
                }
                else{
                    currentItem.setNext(newItem);
                    newItem.setPrevious(currentItem);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (comparison > 0){
                // new Item is less, insert before
                if (currentItem.previous()!= null){
                    currentItem.previous().setNext(newItem);
                    newItem.setPrevious(currentItem.previous());
                    newItem.setNext(currentItem);
                    currentItem.setPrevious(newItem);
                }else{
                    newItem.setNext(this.root);
                    this.root.setPrevious(newItem);
                    this.root = newItem;
                }

            }
        }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I actually don't think this code will work. If comparison is 0 (i.e. the current item is equal to the new item) then the method will loop endlessly.

Comment: My problem is not here, i am asking about the code above, not other codes

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You asked in your question how this code works and my comment is that it doesn't work so it's not really possible to explain how it works. If you just want an explanation of how the node insertion code works then I suggest reading through https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html

Comment: @sprinter Maybe my English isn't good, i will try to explain more, in the second if statement comparison > 0, the code inside this if statement, has made me confused, because it's the first time i see code like that, it's too complicated for me as a beginner that's why, i need someone to tell my how for example : the previous of current item, will set the next of this previous etc, i hope you understand what i need

Comment: @sprinter if the developer has used LinkedList class, that could be easy, instead of this, but I'm trying to understand, how the developer wrote this code, i mean does this code have a name to search about it, like for example the method that call itself has a name is recursion, i hope my comment is readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added comments, plus some fixes:

```
public boolean addItem(ListItem newItem) {
    if(this.root == null){
        this.root = newItem;
        return true;
    }
    ListItem currentItem = this.root;
    while (currentItem != null){
        int comparison = currentItem.compareTo(newItem);
        if (comparison < 0){                               // if cur < new
            newItem.setPrevious(currentItem.previous());   //   advance cur
            if (currentItem.next()!=null){
                currentItem = currentItem.next();
            } else {                                       //   if end list
                currentItem.setNext(newItem);              //     append new
                newItem.setPrevious(currentItem);
                return true;
            }
        } else if (comparison > 0){
            // new < cur, insert before, fixes made to this part
            newItem.setNext(currentItem);                  // set   new.nxt
            newItem.setPrevious(currentItem.previous());   // set   new.prv
            if (newItem.previous()!= null){                // if    new.prv != 0
                newItem.previous().setNext(newItem);       //   set new.prv.nxt
            else                                           // else
                this.root = newItem;                       //   set root
            currentItem.setPrevious(newItem);              // set   cur.prv
            return true;
        }
        return false;     // return false if duplicate
    }
}
```

---

Using text graphics. Say the new node N is to be inserted after A and before B. Initial state, cur (currentItem) = B:

```
                                  cur         == B
    A <------ B    0 <- N         cur.prv     == A  new.prv = 0
    A ------> B         N -> 0    cur.prv.nxt == B  new.nxt = 0
```

The sequence is:

```
         N -> B                   new.nxt      = cur
    A <- N                        new.prv      = cur.prv
    A -> N                        new.prv.nxt  = new
         N <- B                   cur.prv      = new
```

resulting in

```
    A -> N -> B
    A <- N <- B
```